# Import package from subfolder: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have this directory structure:

```
src
  MyPackageFile1.java
  MyPackageFile2.java
vendor
  something.jar
Example.java
```

Note that all files under `src` have a `package com.example;` declaration, while `Example.java` doesn't belong to that package: it is an example of usage of that package (so it has `import xyz.pushpad.*;`).

I successfully compile with:

```
javac -classpath vendor/something.jar src/*.java Example.java
```

However when I run:

```
java Example
```

I get:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/DeliveryException
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyPackageFile1
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 7 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyPackageFile1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MyPackageFile1.java` and `MyPackageFile1.java` are declared in package `com.example`, then there are three problems:

1. Your source directory structure is wrong.  It should be this:

   ```
   src
      com
         example
            MyPackageFile1.java
            MyPackageFile2.java
   ```
2. You are using the wrong classpath separator.  Since you are using Linux (based on the pathname syntax), the classpath separator is `:` not `;`.
3. Classpath you are using to run the code is wrong.  The `java` command line should be something like this:

   ```
   java -cp vendor/something.jar:src:. Example
   ```

---

However, this is all very hacky.

- Unless your codebase needs to be modularized as multiple code trees, then you should put your Example source code into the `src` directory; e.g.

  ```
  src
     Example.java
     com
        example
           MyPackageFile1.java
           MyPackageFile2.java
  ```
- It is a bad idea to put your source code and compiled code into the same tree.  A better idea is to use the `-d` option; e.g.

  ```
  mkdir bin
  javac -cp bin:vendor/something.jar -d bin 
       src/Example.java 
       src/com/example/MyPackageFile1.java
       src/com/example/MyPackageFile12java

  java -cp bin:vendor/something.jar Example
  ```
- You should be using a build tool of some kind ... if you want your builds to be consistent and reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the compile command the run command also needs the jar file on the classpath

```
java -cp vendor/something.jar;src com.example.Example
```

where `Example.java` is moved to new directory `src/com/something`